# Why set value to 0 rather than deleting it?

Tags: solidity, tokens, storage

In this example contract: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol

The removeToken method is supposed to delete a token; the token _tokenId no longer exists. So why does it do `tokenOwner[_tokenId] = 0;` instead of `delete tokenOwner[_tokenId];`?

Surely setting the value to 0 does not actually delete it? Wouldn't that mean that the contract will always take more storage space, never going down, even when the tokens are burnt?

Answer (score 6):

As there is no `null` in Solidity all variables are considered to be empty if their value is `0` or similar (I guess `""` for strings). So setting an integer to 0 basically deletes it.

`delete` also doesn't do anything else than set the value to `0` for integers. So doing `tokenOwner[_tokenId] = 0;` is equal to `delete tokenOwner[_tokenId];`

Comment: Is it the same in terms of gas? Is setting a variable to 0 costs negative gas (returns gas to sender)?

Comment: You never get gas actually returned to you but yes, setting variable to its default value reduces gas usage of the transaction