# Delete an entry from mapping vs. setting it to zero

Tags: solidity, erc-721, mapping

In most ERC721 `setApprovalForAll()` implementations, to revoke approval, the mapping is set to 0, instead of deleting the entry. I wonder what happens if many users have many approvals revoked, wouldn't deleting save a lot of storage in the mapping?

To put it into code, it would look like I have a mapping:

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) private _operatorApprovals;
```

What is the difference between `delete _operatorApprovals[owner][operator];` and `_operatorApprovals[owner][operator] = 0;`

Thank you in advance.

**Update/Answer**

1. `delete` is the same as setting to default value. [StackExchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58495/understanding-more-about-delete-keyword-in-solidity).
2. `mapping` does not keep track of the keys, nor does it have a length. [Medium](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tutorial-all-about-mappings-29a12269ee14).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete _operatorApprovals[owner][operator]` is the same as `_operatorApprovals[owner][operator] = 0` because there is no `null` value in Solidity and setting the value to 0 is the same as deleting it.

See: [Why set value to 0 rather than deleting it?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42478/why-set-value-to-0-rather-than-deleting-it)

Answer (score 1):

It is the same in Solidity. Deleting the value or setting the value as 0